# get names of all dynamic and second level imports

Tags: python

I work on a complex project with many sub directories/packages.

Is there a way to print all **second+ level/dynamic modules** that are used in a given project directory?

If, for example, i use the following import: `from core.dependency.checkpoints_dependency.checkpoints_manager import CheckpointsManager` or `import scipy`, i wish `core.dependency.checkpoints_dependency.checkpoints_manager` and `scipy` to be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try parsing the directory with os.walk and then check for the ones that are in system modules:

```
import sys
import os

all_modules = []

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY):
    module_names = set(sys.modules)
    modules_in_file = [sys.modules[name] for name in module_names]
    all_modules.extend(modules_in_file)

print(set(all_modules))
```